# Fixing Moq expressions when query has a boolean in it like It.IsAny<bool>()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, xunit, xunit.net

I have my code working correctly, but now need to update my tests so that they pass and fail correctly. My code had to be updated to have a boolean added
to the function `GetNamesByAge(int, List<string)` to `GetNamesByAge(int, List<string, bool)`. I use a mock service below to get the names and then pass it through
my validation checks function in the code.

```
_mockNameService.Setup(x => x.GetNamesByAge(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<List<string>>(), It.IsAny<bool>())).Returns(NamesSpecificationMockData.GetNames());
```

After the mock service calls GetNames, it gives back the mocked names.

Then I do this in the test (this is a fact test):

```
_validationService = new ValidaiService(_mockNameService.Object);

var result = _validationService.ValidateNames(namesData);
```

The issue is the the `VaidateNames(namesData)` now has code like so (the true and false search for archived names, where true is valid and false is archived):

```
var validNames = _variableService.GetNamesByAget(age, names, true);
var archivedNames = _variableService.GetNamesByAget(age, names, false);

bool hasValidNames = false;
bool hasArchivedNames = false;

foreach (var item in validNames)
{
    // Save names

    hasValidNames = true;
}

    if (hasValidNames)
{
    // return success
}

foreach (var item in archivedNames)
{
    // Save names

    hasArchivedNames = true;
}

    if (hasArchivedNames)
{
    // return errors
}

// if we get here we have more checks in the `ValidateNames()` in the check.
```

I am confused as to 2 things:

1. If I use `It.IsAny<bool>()`, then I can never get past these two checks which I need to do.
2. If I use `x.GetNamesByAge(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<List<string>>(), true))`, then the other `GetNamesByAge()` function will be null which will fail on the foreach.

How do I get these two issues above solved?

Comment: Can you not setup the method twice for the two different inputs and with two different outputs?

Comment: By that I specifically mean `_mockNameService.Setup(x => x.GetNamesByAge(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<List<string>>(), true)).Returns(NamesSpecificationMockData.GetValidNames());` and `_mockNameService.Setup(x => x.GetNamesByAge(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<List<string>>(), false)).Returns(NamesSpecificationMockData.GetArchivedNames());`. I'm not posting an answer because I'm not completely sure it would work.

Comment: What John said would work as you intend. I’d always recommend using known types over It.IsAny in general. If you can’t use the mechanism that John recommended, you can always look into SetupSequence

Comment: you are right. you can do separate setups and returns with the data you want which solves the problem. didn't know you could do that but makes sense.